# Advanced "Like" system with defense from click fraud

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cookies

I am not professional so doesnt kick me so hard for these questions:)
You can still kick me for my perfect English (* sarcasm *)

I want to realize "like" system on my site.
The main problem there is no registration. Thats mean likes has no limits on clicks.

1. As I understand I can make likes click-filter by IP, writing IPs liked selected ID in mySQL. But its not really good idea for users with same IP.
2. I can make cookie file and write there ids of likes. It protects from noobs, but it is not problem to off cookie or clear it and start click fraud again.
3. And the last thing how to prevent manual script executing of like increase? For example my script called "addlike.php". It is not so hard to send direct POST requests, requests, requests. Like this "http://example.com/addlike.php?id=2" n-times, for example changing IDs.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem you're having is the main reason why websites require a log in before the user can submit input like votes, likes, etc. If you absolutely need the user to be anonymous, a combination of the methods you listed is your best defense as far as I know. It also depends on your use case:

If your target users are often on the same internet connection, IP filtering alone isn't a good solution as you stated, since only one person will be able to submit per IP. You could however create a maximum number of submissions per IP (say 10). If your users are legitimate and there are no more than 10 people on the same IP, their likes will work fine. If there was a hacker trying to spam the system, they would only get 10 likes in before they're throttled. It's a trade off that you'll have to decide.

Filtering by cookie is always a good plan to protect against regular users with little technical knowledge, but can definitely be exploited by someone who's building scripts. You give the user a unique id, store it in a cookie, and only allow one 'like' per unique id. This will stop users from simply refreshing the page, or opening a new tab to 'like' a second time.

It's important to note that none of these techniques will work against distributed bots. If someone has access to a large number of unique IP addresses that can run scripts they provide, you have no easy way to detect and prevent them.

Edit:

I'm not completely clear what your third technique is doing. If you are simply increasing a number every time, you are only protecting against replay attacks (attacker replaying the same request over and over). A smart attacker will notice the increment and include that into their script.

Comment: Good idea with max number of submissions per IP. Can you comment 3rd question please?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your third question.